# How to make custom video player applicable to multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, fullpage.js

I have multiple HTML videos on my page, and want to apply this custom video player to them. The thing is, this only works for the first video, and not for the second, third and fourth.
I have no idea where to start. 
I made a fiddle of the current state: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxse/xx7j91ou/3/)

My Javascript

```
 /* Get Our Elements */
  const player = document.querySelector('.player');
  const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
  const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
  const progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
  const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
  const skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
  const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');

  /* Build out functions */
  function togglePlay() {
    const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[method]();
  }

  function updateButton() {
    const icon = this.paused ? '►' : '❚❚';
    toggle.textContent = icon;
  }

  function skip() {
    video.currentTime += parseFloat(this.dataset.skip);
  }

  function handleRangeUpdate() {
    video[this.name] = this.value;
  }

  function handleProgress() {
    const percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
    progressBar.style.flexBasis = `${percent}%`;
  }

  function scrub(e) {
    const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
    video.currentTime = scrubTime;
  }

  /* Hook up the event listners */
  video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
  video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);

  toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  skipButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));
  ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));
  ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('mousemove', handleRangeUpdate));

  let mousedown = false;
  progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
  progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
  progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
  progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);


  $('video').on('ended', function() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
  });
```

I want this script to work on every video element on the page:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxse/xx7j91ou/3/)

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
  /* Get Our Elements */

  $('.player').each(function() {
    var player = $(this).get(0);
    var video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
    var progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
    var progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
    var toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
    var skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
    var ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');

    /* Build out functions */
    function togglePlay() {
      const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
      video[method]();
    }

    function updateButton() {
      const icon = this.paused ? '►' : '❚❚';
      toggle.textContent = icon;
    }

    function skip() {
      video.currentTime += parseFloat(this.dataset.skip);
    }

    function handleRangeUpdate() {
      video[this.name] = this.value;
    }

    function handleProgress() {
      const percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
      progressBar.style.flexBasis = `${percent}%`;
    }

    function scrub(e) {
      const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
      video.currentTime = scrubTime;
    }

    /* Hook up the event listners */
    video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
    video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
    video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);

    toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
    skipButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));
    ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));
    ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('mousemove', handleRangeUpdate));

    let mousedown = false;
    progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
    progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
    progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
    progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);


    $('video').on('ended', function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kq5hdw0m/