# HTML5 Video pause instead of stop

Tags: html, video, pause

I'm trying to modify a script from this thread [How to make custom video player applicable to multiple videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471133/how-to-make-custom-video-player-applicable-to-multiple-videos/)

Javascript:

```
/* Get Our Elements */
  const player = document.querySelector('.player');
  const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
  const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
  const progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
  const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
  const skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
  const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');

  /* Build out functions */
  function togglePlay() {
    const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
    video[method]();
  }

  function updateButton() {
    const icon = this.paused ? '►' : '❚❚';
    toggle.textContent = icon;
  }

  function skip() {
    video.currentTime += parseFloat(this.dataset.skip);
  }

  function handleRangeUpdate() {
    video[this.name] = this.value;
  }

  function handleProgress() {
    const percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
    progressBar.style.flexBasis = `${percent}%`;
  }

  function scrub(e) {
    const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
    video.currentTime = scrubTime;
  }

  /* Hook up the event listners */
  video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
  video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);

  toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  skipButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));
  ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));
  ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('mousemove', handleRangeUpdate));

  let mousedown = false;
  progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
  progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
  progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
  progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);


  $('video').on('ended', function() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maxse/xx7j91ou/3/

I just want to make the pause button a real pause button, because actually works like a stop button, when you click it set the progress bar to 0. I want to really pause the video.

It might be so simple to do it, but I have no idea. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix to it :

The following functions resets the `currentTime` of the  video when a button is clicked just get rid of it and the problem is fixed.

```
 //Delete this function
 function scrub(e) {
      const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
      video.currentTime = scrubTime;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kq5hdw0m/8/

Working example

Comment: Thank you! But I guess it's not that easy because if I get rid of it other functions like navigation through progress bar doesn't work :(

Comment: Ok let me just fix that up

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I mean when you click on the progress bar to jump through it and go forward or backward through the video

Comment: I was looking through it tried diffrent things for diffrent functions but if i change one thing something else breakes I can't provide a proper answer at the moment sorry